# Word for unused in a while?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I'm looking for a word which can fit the gap in the sentence:

"My french is a little bit ______ since I haven't used it in a while"

I came up with **poor** but hopefully there's a more appropriate word.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make no mistake about it, by far the most idiomatic way to say that is with the word [**rusty**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rusty):

> (of knowledge or a skill) impaired by lack of recent practice

Something that's rusty has been affected by rust. This is just like a piece of metal that has been lying around your backyard unused for a long time. And what happens to metal when it's under constant exposure to the atmosphere? It gets covered with rust. The same thing can happen to your language skills if you haven't been practicing them for a while—they might get rusty.

Examples:

> My French is a little bit **rusty** since I haven't been using it for a while.
>
> My Spanish is a bit **rusty** these days because where I live there is nobody to practice speaking it with.

Answer (score 3):

The word commonly used in BrE is "rusty" because the steel tool you don't use becomes rusty.

Comment: This isn't specific to British English, it's also very common in the US.

Answer (score 3):

The word "rusty" provided in other answers so far is probably the most idiomatic for the specific example provided.

An alternative more generally is the adverb ***neglected*** (or the verb ***to neglect***).

> "My French skills have been a little *neglected*. Sorry if I get a word wrong."
>
> "Please excuse the mess; I've been *neglecting* my chores."

Answer (score 2):

How about ***neglected***?

> [Dictionary.com - neglect](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/neglected)
>   *v.* 2. to be remiss in the care or treatment of:
>   *to neglect one's family; to neglect one's appearance.*

As already noted, "rusty" is probably most appropriate (though idiomatic) for the example sentence given, but *neglected* may be more literally appropriate and translate better in other situations. As noted in the accepted answer, when metal objects are *neglected* (especially outdoors), they become *rusty*, which is the source of the idiom.